# How to put capybara output html to a specific folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

When I use the "Show me the page" step, with Capybara / Cucumber, can I control where the files get output?  I can't seem to find the config for this, and my google fu is failing me.

Right now it appears that by default they go to the root of my rails folder and clutter up things there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed a config option that allows you to specify where to output the files:

> Capybara.save_and_open_page_path

I believe it was added in the latest version (0.3.9)

In your env.rb file you can do something like:

```
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = '/Users/jsboulanger/my-rails-project/tmp'
```

In Capybara 2.10, `Capybara::save_and_open_page=` is deprecated.  Instead, call `Capybara::save_path=`

Comment: Brilliant!  Though, it looked like the path was relative to my rails project, so I could just use:

Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = 'tmp'

But it worked great - thanks!

Comment: I recommend using the operating system's tmp file dir.  AFAIK, there is no process that will clean these capybara files out of the rails project tmp dir. `Capybara.save_path = '/tmp'`

Comment: Ruby Style recommends avoiding double-colons (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#double-colons):  `Cabybara.save_path =`

Answer (score 7):

Nice. Thanks for this.

To be really neat about it I added the config line to `config/environments/test.rb`, since you generally only use capybara in test, and that works fine.

Since there's a bunch of subfolders in tmp/ I used:

```
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = 'tmp/capybara'
```

and created that folder.